# Android: Why am I getting NullPointerExceptions?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use Android TMX Loader to load a game map. I keep having problems that are/seem to be because of the file not being loaded. I used the example provided, and just substituted my file, but no matter what path I use, it won't load. I either get a file not found exception, or a null pointer exception on the line(s) that load the file. I've verified that the assets are being put into the APK with WinRar, and they are indeed there...

Here's my code:

```
ImageView mapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    loadWorld("World.tmx");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/*
 * public void displayMap() { Display display =
 * getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); Point size = new Point();
 * display.getSize(size); int width = size.x; int height = size.y;
 * 
 * }
 */

public void loadWorld(String path) {
    // Start the parser, get back TMX data object
    TileMapData t = TMXLoader.readTMX(path, this);

    mapView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.MapImage);

    // Create a Bitmap from the tilemap data
    Bitmap mapImage = TMXLoader.createBitmap(t, this, 0, t.layers.size());

    // Set the imageview to show the map, if we have one
    if (mapImage != null) {
        mapView.setImageBitmap(mapImage);
    }
    // Map loading problem, inform the user.
    else {
        Toast errorMessage = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Map could not be loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        errorMessage.show();
    }
}
```

Here is the latest LogCat stack:

```
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fionaheiss.shovelshovel/com.fionaheiss.shovelshovel.DisplayMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2006)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1166)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4486)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at com.fionaheiss.shovelshovel.DisplayMap.loadWorld(DisplayMap.java:38)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at com.fionaheiss.shovelshovel.DisplayMap.onCreate(DisplayMap.java:20)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4635)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
12-31 07:44:25.046: E/AndroidRuntime(18074):    ... 11 more
```

What is it that's going wrong? I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: That would be `Bitmap mapImage = TMXLoader.createBitmap(t, this, 0, t.layers.size());
`

Comment: But, it varies depending on what I set the file path as...

Comment: Well that suggests that `t` is null. That will happen if you give it the wrong path, I suspect...

Comment: swap two lines
     loadWorld("World.tmx"); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: In debug `t` is indeed null, so apparently I can't get the filepath correct... I have tried about 10 different configurations, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    loadWorld("World.tmx");  //<< here

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

you are trying to find `ImageView` `MapImage`  before adding layout to current Activity so change your code as:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loadWorld("file:///android_asset/World.tmx");
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this, but still get a `RuntimeException`

Comment: @SeanHeiss : if you do this then error must be changed post new log after changing this

Comment: @SeanHeiss : where is World.tmx file you have placed?

Comment: OK, I'll swap the new one out with the old one.

Comment: Done. It is in the assets folder, at the root of my project. Like I said, all the assets are correctly packed into the APK.

Comment: Even if I set the path to "assets/World.tmx", it still gives me a NullPointException.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, but now I get a file not found exception...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21959/discussion-between-sean-heiss-and--k)

Answer (score 0):

This means that either t or t.layers is null.